# Retrieving ids from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble accessing the "model_id" and "brand_id" from the foreach loop that I am using.

They are the right field names, because I have echoed them successfully, and I have also "var_dumped" the array, and the IDs are there. It is just a case of implementing the relevant links on each list section. Below is the code I have.

```
<?
$output = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM bikes, bikeTypes WHERE bikes.model_id = bikeTypes.model_id");
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($output))
 {
   $result[$row['model']][] = $row;
 }

foreach ($result as $category => $values) {
  echo "<li><a href='test.php?id=" . $row['model_id'] . "'>".$category.'</a><ul>';
    foreach ($values as $value) 
      {
      echo "<li><a href='details.php?id=" . $row['brand_id'] . "'>" . $value['bikeName'] . "</a></li>";
      }
  echo '</ul>';   
  echo '</li>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Your rowset was stored into `$result` in the while loop. You then loop over `$result` using the variable `$values`, but are using `$row['model_id']` inside. Change to `$values['model_id']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $value instead of $row in foreach loop

```
foreach ($values as $value) 
      {
      echo "<li><a href='details.php?id=" . $value['brand_id'] . "'>" . $value['bikeName'] . "</a></li>";
      }
```

Try this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($output))
 {
   $result[] = $row;
 }
//var_dump($result);
foreach ($result as $key => $val) {
  echo "<li><a href='test.php?id=" . $val['model_id'] . "'>".$key.'</a><ul>';
  echo "<li><a href='details.php?id=" . $val['brand_id'] . "'>" . $val['bikeName'] . "</a></li>";
  echo '</ul>';   
  echo '</li>';
 }
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the tip, didn't work though. the id field is still blank

Comment: try to debug  $result. I'm not sure why did you create array like this $row['model']][];

Comment: hey there, I have added var_dump($result) under the menu if that helps?

Comment: thanks for that! we are nearly there, have updated the site. So need to group the links with "id=1" for example into one <li>ADVENTURE</li> (the column is called "model" if that helps) item. Nearly there though, brilliant, thanks! :)

Comment: I'll glad if this works for u

Answer (score 1):

In your foreach you define $category and $values and in that loop you're using $row. Shouldn't you be using `$values['brand_id']` ?